# Calculate my income tax

Tags: code-golf, math, number

#### Background

Here in the UK<sup>1</sup>, these are the income tax rules:

- You get a personal allowance (untaxed) of up to £12,570:

  - If you earn less than £100,000, you get the full £12,570 as personal allowance
  - For every £2 over £100,000, your personal allowance goes down by £1
- After the personal allowance, the next £37,700 is taxed at the "basic rate" of 20%
- After that, the next £99,730 is taxed at the "higher rate" of 40%
- Finally, anything above this is taxed at the "additional rate" of 45%

<sub>1: This isn't actually the case in Scotland; only England, Wales and Northern Ireland.</sub>

#### Your task

Using the above tax rules, take in an annual salary (as a positive integer) and calculate the income tax.

#### Test cases

```python
Input    Output
12570    0
50000    7486
80000    19432
120000   39432
200000   75588.5
```

Note: the final test case can be any of 75588, 75588.5, or 75589 (any is fine)

#### Clarifications

- You can choose whether to make the personal allowance an integer or keep it as a float

  - e.g. if the input is £100,003, the personal allowance can be £12,569, £12,568.50, or £12,568
- The same goes for the final output. If it ends up as a float, you can make it an integer or keep it as a float

  - (see the final test case)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25402/114446)

Comment: Presumably your personal allowance can never be negative.

Comment: @Simd yes, after something like £125,140 you have £0 personal allowance.

Comment: It seems that these tax rules apply only in England, Wales, and Northern Ireland (i.e. UK except Scotland)

Comment: Isn’t there something called national insurance contributions too?

Comment: @matteo_c yes, in Scotland they have a different system, but I didn't feel that information was necessary for the challenge.

Comment: @Simd yes there is, but we are ignoring it for this challenge

Comment: This is actually quite similar to how Australian taxation works, which makes sense given we're part of y'all anyway :p

Comment: @TheThonnu of course, your challenge your rules, but I think it would be better if iin the background section were specified the countries where this system is applied

Comment: @matteo_c done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>32</s> 31 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
5ÐD(20)zI•5HwŸJ}Ütæ•žFвT*-Dd**O
```

Port of [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256013/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f9PAEFw0jA80qz0cNi0w9yo/u8Ko9PKfk8DIg9@g@twubQrR0XVK0tPz//zc0MgACAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKS/X/TwxNcNIwMNKsqHzUsMvUoP7rDq/bwnJLDy4Dco/vcLmwK0dJ1SdHS8v@v8z/a0MjU3EDH1AAIdCzApKERmAKTBrEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
5            # Push a 5
 ÐD          # Triplicate + Duplicate so there are four 5s on the stack
   (         # Negate the top one
    20       # Push 20
      )      # Wrap all five values on the stack into a list: [5,5,5,-5,20]
       z     # Get 1/value for each of them: [0.2,0.2,0.2,-0.2,0.05]
I            # Push the input
 •5HwŸJ}Ütæ• # Push compressed integer 90598507370046338479
  žFв        # Convert 90598507370046338479 to base-16384 as list: 
             #  [1257,5027,10000,12514,13743]
     T*      # Multiply each by 10: [12570,50270,100000,125140,137430]
I      -     # Subtract each from the input
        D    # Duplicate this list
         d   # Pop and do a non-negative (>=0) check for each
          *  # Multiply the values at the same positions (negative values have become 0)
*            # Multiply the values at the same positions with list [0.2,0.2,0.2,-0.2,0.05]
 O           # Sum everything together
             # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•5HwŸJ}Ütæ•` is `90598507370046338479` and `•5HwŸJ}Ütæ•žFв` is `[1257,5027,10000,12514,13743]`.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 99 bytes

Works with floats and rounds the final result.

```javascript
n=>[137430.45,37700.4,.2].map(v=>x+=v%1*(n-(n-=m(n-~~v))),x=0,n-=(m=v=>v>0&&v)(12570-m(n-1e5)/2))|x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczBDoIwDAbgO0/BRbLqGBtjbh7GixgPBNFogBExCwfDq88hHJTYNE3T70/vhS368nHrnnFrzpW7aNfq/Mi4zDglmcBcSuoXTNITaYoOWZ0PO203bIva2Ldu/BhHCwB40BT7C2q0T9mcRpEFxFIhaTylWCUgSQFegytN25u6IrW5osscCQHCJAlp8GuC@lpMZmq/YvXF7JDxNFi/ngKz8z/@4cWlEEoR4d4)

```javascript
n =>                 // n = input
[                    // in this array, the integer part is the threshold (T)
                     // and the decimal part is the tax rate (R)
  137430.45,         //   T = 99730 + 37700, R = 45%
  37700.4,           //   T = 37700, R = 40%
  .2                 //   T = 0, R = 20%
]                    //
.map(v =>            // for each entry v:
  x +=               //   add to x:
    v % 1 *          //     the tax rate multiplied by
    ( n -            //     the difference between the current value of n
      ( n -=         //     and the updated value of n, which is:
          m(n - ~~v) //       n - max(0, n - threshold)
      )              //
    ),               //
  x = 0,             //   start with x = 0
  n -=               //   start by applying the personal allowance
    ( m = v =>       //   m is a helper function taking v ...
      v > 0 && v     //   ... and returning max(0, v)
    )                //
    (                //   personal allowance:
      12570 -        //     12570 - max(0, n - 100000) / 2
      m(n - 1e5) / 2 //
    )                //
)                    // end of map()
| x                  // return the final value of x
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>83</s> <s>80</s> 77 bytes

*-3 thanks to @Max by removing the `0` from the beginning of the floating points.*

*-3 thanks to @tsh by using integers which are then divided instead of floats and changing the personal allowance operation.*

```python
lambda m:sum(([4]*37700+[8]*99730+[9]*m)[:m-max(0,min(62570-m//2,12570))])/20
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5BbsMgEEX3nGLEClwcY2wCtuTeICdwvHBVWUEKYMUkSq_RbTeWquZOuU0oaWcz78_8P5qv2_wRDt6t31O3_zmHKdf33XG0b-8j2HY5W0L6esgqpTh_6fWQNY2qIjVDZmnf2tyOV8KZNY5shVQ8t0UhWPmLlA60EPzv6GfoMMZpARxJHgtUrbdIJyybuhKoFElUSSSOJim13sgY3izz0QSC9w5TNPkTGA_GQWgRgGEeujj490C0AMwn4wIxDOevmE0kCUoZviyYefr8bF2f_QE)

Fun use of Python indexing and list multiplication.

Comment: I think you can remove the leading zero from `0.2` etc.

Comment: `lambda m:sum(([4]*37700+[8]*99730+[9]*m)[:m-max(0,min(62570-m//2,12570))])/20`

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 49 bytes

```
ＩΣ×Ｉ⪪”‴⌈↷¶»^w⁷k²zV” Ｅ⁻ＮＩ⪪”←¶➙～!¬‴″ζＣＥR⁵kςⅈ” ∧›ι⁰ι
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjeXBRRl5pVoOCcWl2gEl-ZqhGTmphZDuQU5mSUaSnpGChCkC6IMTJV0FJQUlDQ1dRR8Ews0fDPzSos1PPMKSkv8SnOTUos0gBLI2g2NTM0NFEwNjICkoQEIKACFDE2AlLG5ibEBzDigNse8FA33otTEEqApmToKBkChTE0wsF5SnJRcDHXz8mgl3bIcpdhlRmDjIIIA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
           Ｎ            Input as a number
          ⁻             Vectorised subtract
              ...       Compressed string `12570 50270 100000 125140 137430`
             ⪪          Split on spaces
            Ｉ           Cast to number
         Ｅ              Map over values
                    ι   Current value
                   ›    Is greater than
                     ⁰  Literal integer `0`
                  ∧     Logical And
                      ι Current value
  ×                     Vectorised multiply by
     ...                Compressed string `.2 .2 .2 -.2 .05`
    ⪪                   Split on spaces
   Ｉ                    Cast to number
 Σ                      Take the sum
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

73 bytes for a version that calculates the personal allowance as an integer first:

```
Ｎθ≔⟦⁹⁹⁷³⁰¦³⁷⁷⁰⁰⌈⟦⁰⁻¹²⁵⁷⁰÷⌈⟦⁰⁻θＸχ⁵⟧²⟧⟧η≔⁰ζＦ³«≔⌊⟦θ⊟η⟧ε≧⁺×∕ι⁵εζ≧⁻εθ»Ｉ⁺ζ×θ·⁴⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY8xC8IwEIVn@ysyXiBKbZUiTqKLg1LETRyiVnvQprVpVBR/e7y0iqBZLpd7972XfSqrfSEza@eqNPXS5LukgjMfexOt8aRgMxpFoS9YGEU@lYW8YW5y2Lg7KqOhHwwjauaqnuEFDwn8S86CxcWVuH16GnK@5YIFrmwFS79WNLxTdywqBiFnD6/zHhClJTagEtKGkJC2s5BlK1rhKa0hzowWbI15ouEdB52lU7f0340mIY0Fc59@enGFqoap1C0M7h8cefu9AaXnfGxt4Ltju5dMvgA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>132</s> 129 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [@The Thonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu)*

```haskell
r#(-1.0)=r;r#l=min r l
g(t,r)(l,p)=(t+r#l*p/20,r-r#l)
f x=fst$foldl g(0,x)$zip[max(12570-max(x-1e5)0/2)0,37700,99730,-1][0,4,8,9]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TdA7TsQwEAbg3qcYaVPYMGbtPLAj8A3oKKMUEZvsRjibyPGKCNFwDpptEBfgMtyGPMiKqX59I9m_5uPrUPTPpbXn8-fJV1z_vLsN5fJGMOPu3Maapj6CA0v21KNj1GLHDPXX4-qq24YCHR8jIxUMpup9ULV2Z2FPBQ4seK27rCkGKsNECT6lgcsyYWIbMoGRUkJgmqpIIJd5JjBGjWn-V-Tbl71_KvqyBwMZgXGWh3CKguFCiRhnJhXr21X1RWUaR-HKMlw9-s-zzqySRGuWE-KmTyuo4Q1ojS2Dew6XQjlpivEsBrqTf_Tu4QgB9If2BdzSfT3mLw)

Comment: Nice answer (+1). I think you could change `100000` to `1e5` to save 3 bytes: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TdA7TsQwEAbg3qcYaVPYMGbtPLAj8A3oKKMUEZvsRjibyPGKCNFwDpptEBfgMtyGPMiKqX59I9m_5uPrUPTPpbXn8-fJV1z_vLsN5fJGMOPu3Maapj6CA0v21KNj1GLHDPXX4-qq24YCHR8jIxUMpup9ULV2Z2FPBQ4seK27rCkGKsNECT6lgcsyYWIbMoGRUkJgmqpIIJd5JjBGjWn-V-Tbl71_KvqyBwMZgXGWh3CKguFCiRhnJhXr21X1RWUaR-HKMlw9-s-zzqySRGuWE-KmTyuo4Q1ojS2Dew6XQjlpivEsBrqTf_Tu4QgB9If2BdzSfT3mLw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/), <s>58 48</s> 33 bytes

```
5D:N20WĖ⁰»+gḊ6ß/ċi∴o@t»k4τ-:0≥**∑
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI1RDpOMjBXxJbigbDCuytn4biKNsOfL8SLaeKItG9AdMK7azTPhC06MOKJpSoq4oiRIiwiIiwiMTIwMDAwIl0=)

- -15 thanks to lyxal

Port of Neil's Charcoal answer

#### Explanation

```python
5D:                             # Push 5 and quadruplicate
   N                            # Negate the top one
    20                          # Push 20
      W                         # Wrap the stack in a list
       Ė                        # Reciprocal of each
        ⁰                       # Push the input
         »...»                  # Push the base-255 compressed integer 12570050270100000125140137430
              k4τ               # Convert to list: [12570,50270,100000,125140,137430]
                 -              # Subtract each from the input
                  :             # Duplicate this list
                   0≥           # Check if each element is ≥0
                     *          # Multiply with the list so negative values are now 0
                      *         # Multiply together
                       ∑        # And sum, outputting implicitly
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI1RDpOMjBXxJbigbDCu+KfkceOwrvCu+KGlMimwrtcImsySsK7MuKGlMK7SsK7NsmWwrtK4oKAKi06MOKJpSoq4oiRIiwiIiwiMTIwMDAwIl0=) for 40 bytes

Comment: or [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI1RDpOMjBXxJbigbDCuytn4biKNsOfL8SLaeKItG9AdMK7azTPhC06MOKJpSoq4oiRIiwiIiwiMTIwMDAwIl0=) for 33

Comment: @lyxal thanks, updated

Answer (score 2):

## QB64, 183 bytes

```
p=12570:If i>100000Then
p=p-Int((i-100000)/2):If p<0Then p=0
endif
l=p+37700:m=l+99730:If i>m Then
t=.45*(i-m):i=m
endif
If i>l Then
t=t+.4*(i-l):i=l
endif
If i>p Then t=t+.2*(i-p)
?t
```

Comment: Suggest `(i-p)/5` instead of `.2*(i-p)`

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>120</s> <s>107</s> 102 bytes

- -18 thanks to ceilingcat

```c
#define F+fdim(i
f(i){i=fmin(37700,i=F,F-i+12570,F,1e5)/2)))/5+.4*fmin(99730,i=F,37700))F,99730)*.45;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzRisIwEEXf@xWDImSaqabV0JUSH/MT7j5I08gUWxd38aXUTzfGOA934HDPbYtz24awdJ3nsQMrveNBcOYF48TGDzyKbV0rRWws2YJlWelakaWy07ipEHGj5XqXp@Z@X28/zeQgWkoI8/VON3Pg8R@GUyzer@wQpgzgjfj4Y6bPrlbx6CtlWaWXUlFRzgR532RR8teb6A038IgAeikxQoDfW1zzYrFyYA6wct/j4q0QeJH3iE02h2frL6fzXyguwws)